# Does Grizzly Project take care of buffer overflow or denial of service attacks?

Tags: java, jersey, denial-of-service, grizzly

I have searched a lot, but still don't understand whether using Grizzly means that I am protected against those attacks or that I should do some more effort?

Currently, the only thing I do in my program is that I deploy my resource classes (annotated by @Path - I'm using Jersey) to the Grizzly, by the following code:

```
final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages","MyServer.resources");
SelectorThread threadSelector;
try{
    threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(
 uri, initParams);
    System.out.println("Press enter to stop server...");
    System.in.read();
    threadSelector.stopEndpoint();
}catch(...){...}
```

In my resource methods, I may access a list of JAXB beans which I don't specify any size for it (I don't know if it is possible to check the size at this point to avoid getting large requests-if it is possible, it will be a great help if somebody tell me!), So, I'm afraid that an attacker may send consecutive and large requests (my normal request size should be less than 6 beans!) and result to denial of service - I am just starting to learn security risks and handling them, my first attempt!

I will check the size in the request handler method's body, which is after the request is completely received by the server. Is it enough?

The Grizzly documents say that it has a good buffer management (I may be mixing buffer overflow with denial of service), but I don't know whether I should set any settings or is it by default protecting?

EDIT:

I have received a good answer to part of my question, but, I'm still looking for some hints particularly about the Grizzly or Jersey and whether there is a single point of entry in which I can make some checks for all incoming requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java you are pretty much immune from classic buffer overrun attacks, unless you are using native code libraries to process stuff you get from the net.

On the other hand, protecting yourself from denial of service attacks tends to require a whole-of-system approach.

**EDIT**

By "whole of system" approach, I mean one that takes account of the impact on your network bandwidth, infrastructure and back-end servers as well as just your web server.  For instance, an attack directed at your network bandwith or DNS can take you off the air irrespectively of how you implement your webserver.  At the other end, someone could target aspects of your web application; e.g. knowledge that a particular query is very expensive ... or that it leaks resources and eventually crashes your application.

(I'm not an expert on this.  I'm just trying to point out that just looking at your web server platform is not sufficient ... if you really care about defending against DDoS.)

Comment: thanks, can you be a little bit more specific about 'whole-of-system' approach, giving an example? I didn't find a concrete approach with this name in programming and security, so it should be a general expression.. sorry, I'm not familiar in the field and I'm not native English.

Comment: Yeah, for same reason, I'm looking for how I can control misusing of things such as expensive queries (like, controlling the number of incoming requests in a time limit) in jersey, while each request is handled directly by a response method and I don't see where these requests are initially received and then directed to those response methods.